# Drupal 7 - module.install file schema error

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have written below code in custom_notifications.install file.

When I am trying to enable that module its giving me error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

kindly help me with this.

```
function custom_notifications_schema() {

 $schema['custom_notification_log'] = array(
'fields' => array(
  'cnl' => array('type' => 'serial', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'not null' => TRUE),
  'notification_type' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 64),
  'notification_type_id' => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE),
  'uid' => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE),
  'viewed_on' => array('type' => 'int', 'unsigned' => TRUE),
)
);
return $schema; 
}
```

Comment: above code seems to be fine.. problem is somewhere else...

Comment: when I remove this function then I am not getting any error. I think there is some error is with function only.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to try:

1) Look at your dblog (`Reports -> Recent log messages`) for PHP errors providing more information.

2) Go to the `Uninstall` tab and see if your module is listed. If it is, then uninstall it, then attempt to re-install.

Answer (score 0):

SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE. try removing the unsigned and not null keys for your cnl field